# Is this complex analysis proof rigorous?

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, connectedness

I was reading *Complex Analysis* by **Serge Lang**. The Theorem 1.1 of the third chapter states:

> Let $U$ be a connected open set, and let $f$ be a holomorphic function on $U$. If $f^{\prime}=0$ then $f$ is a constant.

It was proven by considering a curve $\gamma$ and showing that $f(\alpha)=f(\beta)$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the points connected by $\gamma$ and the function $t\to f(\gamma (t))$ is differentiable. Next it shows that for all the points $\alpha, z_0, z_1, \ldots , z_n, \beta$, where $z_i$ is a end and a star point of two curves on a path, $f(z_i)=f(\alpha)$. In other words, if you take the derivative of a path, it's constant on every point joining two curves. Then it claims that this proves the theorem.

Somehow this feels a bit odd since as I understood it, we would have to consider every possible path on the set $U$ to prove that $f$ is constant. Is this really rigorous? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't like this proof (which is entirely correct), you can also use the topological definition of connectedness. Fix $\alpha \in U$ and show that the set $\{ z\in U\ :\ f(z)=f(\alpha)\}$ is closed and open.

Comment: Giuseppe Negro, you should make your comment an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you asked here's an alternative proof. It uses the topological definition of connectedness: a topological space is connected iff its only closed and open sets are the trivial ones. It also uses the calculus fact that a continuous function $f\colon[a, b]\to \mathbb C$ with vanishing derivative on $(a, b)$ is constant. (In calculus, one considers $f\colon [a,b]\to \mathbb R$, but there's no loss of generality, as it suffices to apply this fact to the real and the imaginary part).

Let $U\subset \mathbb C$ be open and let $f\colon U\to \mathbb C$ be (real or complex) differentiable and such that $f'(z)=0$ for all $z\in U$. Let $a\in U$ and 
$$S=\{z\in U\ :\ f(z)=f(a)\}.$$ 
The set $S$ is obviously closed. We show that $S$ is also open and so, since $a\in S$, the only possibility is that $S=U$, that is, $f$ is constant. Let $z\in U$. Since $U$ is open there exists an open disc $D$ such that 
$$z\in D\subset U.$$ 
For all $w\in D$, the segment with extremes in $z$ and $w$ lies entirely in $D$. We parametrize it as 
$$\gamma(t)=z+t(w-z),\qquad t\in[0, 1].$$ 
The composition $f\circ \gamma$ defines a one-variable function with derivative 
$$
\frac{d}{dt} (f\circ \gamma)(t) = f'( z+t(w-z) )(w-z) =0.$$ 
And so $f\circ \gamma$ is a constant, which implies that $f(z)=f(w)$. Since $w$ is arbitrary, $f$ is constant on $D$, which means that $D\subset S$. We have proven that $S$ is open. $\square$.

---

Note that this proof is exactly the same as Lang's, only that it does not consider paths but only small segments (in technical words, it is a "local" proof).

Answer (score 3):

That depends on the definition of connectedness. It looks like you're using the path-connected using differentiable curves:

> A set U is connected if for any two $a, b\in U$ there exists a differentiable function $\gamma: [0,1]\to U$ such that $a=\gamma(0)$ and $b=\gamma(1)$.

Also note that we use the definition of a function being constant:

> A function $f$ is said to be constant on $U$ if for any two $a,b\in U$ we have $f(a)=f(b)$

You don't have to check along all possible paths since the fact that by selecting two points $a$ and $b$ and a path $\gamma$ between them implies that $f(a)=f(b)$ then another path $\tilde \gamma$ between them wouldn't alter anything since the fact that $f(a)=f(b)$ has been established.

Comment: *How* does it depend on the definition of connectedness? Don't forget that we are working on an open set here.

Comment: Because if you don't require $\gamma$ to be differentiable you can't apply the chain rule.

Comment: Your comment has nothing to do with connectedness.

Comment: How do you know that $f(\gamma(t))$ is differentiable? My interpretation is that they use the fact that $\gamma(t)$ is differentiable.

Comment: An open subset of $\mathbb C$ is connected if and only if any two of its points can be joined by a differentiable path. And it's not "them"; it's "he".

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes, I stated that the proof depended on that definition of connectedness. If you instead used the definition from topology that it's connected if you can't decompose it into two disjoint open sets it would be a lot more non-obvious that $\gamma$ existed and $f(\gamma(t))$ is differentiable. That is the rigorousness of the proof is dependent on which defenition we use for connectedness...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is rigorous. And he doesn't have to consider evey possible path in $U$ (and, if he did, why would that make it non-rigorous?). For each two points $\alpha$ and $\beta$, he considers *a* path from $\alpha$ to $\beta$. That's all.